# Is there a way to disable or limit system xrandr probes?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, tv

I am currently suffering from a video card related bug ([S-video output doesn't work in Natty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/763688)) which causes my TV screen to flicker every 10 seconds. According to a Launchpad contributor, this is probably caused by the system running a regular xrandr probe.

Is there any way to safely disable this probe while I wait for a bugfix?

I want to be able to:

- run my machine as normal when the S-video cable is not plugged in
- plug in the cable and choose to output to the TV using the Monitor Preferences tool
- unplug the cable and switch back to normal resolution
- (low priority) boot up with the cable plugged in and have it be detected and used
- not mess everything up

Is this possible? A system setting would be preferable, but a script/command to run after I've got the TV hooked up is acceptable.

Comment: in that bug report one contributor mentioned installing kernel 2.6.34 and booting from that.  Suggest investigate that route (download from herehttp://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ )

Comment: that didn't work for me, so I'd prefer a solution on top of the current system, but thanks for the suggestion, it may work for someone else

Comment: possibly useful documentation: http://live.gnome.org/RandR (see bits about gnome-settings-daemon)

Comment: asked on an X.Org forum http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?57863-Is-there-a-way-to-disable-or-limit-system-xrandr-probes

Comment: Since you have filed as a bug report - [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks!